# Flutter: Bars are not displaying

Tags: flutter, charts

I am trying to display the api value on bar chart,
my api data is look like this

```
{leaves: 3, sick: 2, annual: 0, maternity: 1}
```

**charts.dart**

i am getting this data from login screen, and passing it to the leave screen using shared perference.

i want to display it in bar chart, here is my try to do this

```
class LeavesCharts extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<LeavesSeries> data;

  LeavesCharts({@required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<charts.Series<LeavesSeries, String>> series=[
        charts.Series(
          id: "Leaves",
          data: data,
          domainFn: (LeavesSeries series, _)=>series.totalleave,      
          measureFn: (LeavesSeries series,_)=>series.annual,
          colorFn: (LeavesSeries series,_)=>series.barColor,
        )
    ];

    return 
    Container(
      height: 400,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),

      child: Card(child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text("History of leaves"),
        Expanded(child: charts.BarChart(series,animate: true,))
      ],),
      )
      ,),);
    
  }
}
```

here i am displaying the chart

```
  String annualCount="4";
  String totalleaveCount="4";
  String sickCount="4";
  String maternityCount="1";

class _RequestForLeaveState extends State<RequestForLeave> {

 

//getting values using shared perference
_userDetails() async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      sickCount=myPrefs.getString('sickcount');
      totalleaveCount=myPrefs.getString('totalleave');
      maternityCount=myPrefs.getString('maternitycount');
      annualCount=myPrefs.getString('annualcount');
     ;
    });
  }
 final List<LeavesSeries> data=[
  
    LeavesSeries(
    
    totalleave: totalleaveCount,
    maternity: maternityCount,
    sick:sickCount,
    annual: 3,
    barColor:charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue)
    ),
   
    ];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(        
        appBar: new MyAppBar(
          title: Text("Request for leave"),
          // onpressed: () {
          //   Navigator.push(
          //       context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()));
          // },
        ),
        drawer: drawer(),
        body: LeavesCharts(data:data)
    );
  }
} 
           
    
    
class LeavesSeries {
  String totalleave;
  int annual;
  String sick;
  String maternity;
  final charts.Color barColor;
  

  LeavesSeries({@required this.totalleave,@required this.annual,@required this.sick,@required this.maternity, @required this.barColor});
}
```

but it is not displaying any bar, here is the output

[image]

**update output:**
i initialize varibles with some values and it display bar according to that, but i want 4 bars for each variable, how i can do that?
[image]

please help where i am doing wrong

Comment: what is the reason behind this?

Comment: It looks to me like you create the data object once, with empty strings in it, and don't update it. What happens if you construct the data object at the start of your build function by retrieving the variables from the state?

Comment: @fravolt if i create object after the shared perference then it will get the values, right? i update my code check that please

Comment: I don't think references in Dart will work that way, in `_userDetails()` the 4 variables get updated from the prefs, that should work just fine. Because the state has updated, `build` will be called. However, build will not use these newly set variables in the state, but instead it will access and use the 'old' data object, which contained only empty strings.

Comment: @fravolt please check the updated output, i initialize varibles with some values and it display bar according to that, but i want 4 bars for each variable, how i can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the issue is right now. I just posted an answer below, please check it out and let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data object does not contain the newly set data.

In _userDetails() the 4 variables get updated from the prefs, that should work just fine. Because the state has updated, build will be called. However, build will not use these newly set variables in the state, but instead it will access and use the 'old' data object, which contained only empty strings. It does not get overwritten with your new object.

I suggest putting the data object into the state, using the prefs you already retrieve

```dart
class _RequestForLeaveState extends State<RequestForLeave> {
    LeavesCharts data;

    @override
    initState() {
        super.initState();
        data = LeavesSeries(   
            totalleave: 0,
            maternity: 0,
            sick: 0,
            annual: 0,
            barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue)
        );
    }

    //getting values using shared perference
    _userDetails() async {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() {
            data = LeavesSeries(   
            totalleave: myPrefs.getString('totalleave'),
            maternity: myPrefs.getString('maternitycount'),
            sick: myPrefs.getString('sickcount'),
            annual: myPrefs.getString('annualcount'),
            barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue)
            )
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in `build`, you can access this data object and use it as expected to retrieve all of its values.

Comment: i am getting this error , ```The argument type 'LeavesSeries' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<LeavesSeries>'.``` on ```body: LeavesCharts(data:data)``` line

Comment: You originally set `data` in the state as a `List<LeavesSeries>`, and I (mainly for ease of explaining) made it a single `LeavesSeries` object. If you'll need multiple you can update the `setState` call in my code and put `[` and `]`  around the `LeavesSeries` objects.

Comment: thank you, it helps me, I did some modification, but your logic helped!